# Information_schema not getting generated from jooq for SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, schema, jooq

I am using Jooq Trial for generating code from SQL Server database as a poc. I use the below congifuration. However, it is not generating the information schema during compilation.

```
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip.jooq.generation}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                        <url>${database.url}</url>
                        <user></user>
                        <password></password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <!--<inputSchema></inputSchema> --> <!-- This will generate all schema of db, better to only generate the one 
                                interested in -->
                            <inputCatalog>scm</inputCatalog>
                            <schemata>
                                <schema>
                                    <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>
                                </schema>
                                <schema>
                                    <inputSchema>INFORMATION_SCHEMA</inputSchema>
                                </schema>
                            </schemata>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>org.blackdread.sqltojava.jooq</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
                        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
                        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Log:

> [INFO] Generation finished: scm.dbo: Total: 1.493s, +0.333ms [INFO]
>   [INFO] Excluding empty schema   : scm.INFORMATION_SCHEMA [INFO]
>   Removing excess files

But information_schema is available as views and it is returning me the necessary information too. I'm using windows authentication and not sa.

Answer (score 1):

For historic reasons, jOOQ-meta's `SQLServerDatabase` only queries the `sys.objects` table, not the `sys.all_objects` table, to reverse engineer your database. This should be changed, of course. I have created a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8827

It has been implemented for jOOQ 3.12

#### Workaround

In the meantime, you have these options:

- Extend the `SQLServerDatabase` to adapt its queries to fetch rom `all_objects`, not from `objects` (this is a lot simpler with the professional edition than with the free trial, as you'll get the sources, and the right to patch the source code)
- Use the `JDBCDatabase`, which queries JDBC's `DatabaseMetaData`, instead. This should return content from the `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schemas as well (but currently doesn't give access to e.g. stored procedures)
- Use the generated `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables located in the jOOQ-meta module